# sys.stdout не выводит в файл при компиляции через pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sys

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Для удобства переноса исполняемого файла с ботом в Телеграмме, я использую библиотеку pyinstller для сборки .exe файла. Работает в целом хорошо, но только есть один момент. При аварийном завершении кода в окно терминала пишется текст ошибки и окно после этого быстро пропадает, не давая возможности ошибку посмотреть. Решил сделать вот так:

```
sys.stderr = open('err.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'a')

print('setup complete')
```

При компиляции в .exe и запуске его, оба файла создаются. Ошибки в первый пишутся, а вот во второй файл к примеру та же надпись setup complete уже не попадает. К тому же она и в консоль не выводится. Куда она пропадает?

Если строку sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'a') закомментировать и пересобрать файл без нее, контрольная надпись в консоли уже будет.

Comment: А не проще ли `exe` запускать с перенаправлением вывода в файл? Что-то типа `bot.exe > c:\temp\out.txt 2>c:\temp\err.txt`. А у вас тут может не работать потому, что непонятно, в какой каталог ваш код пытается писать эти файлы, может у него прав нету. Задайте полный путь к файлам, такой, куда заведомо могут все писать.

Comment: Но ведь файл err.txt отрабатывает как и ожидается, ошибки в него попадают. Не выводится стандартный вывод в файл out.txt.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал использовать логгер вместо перенаправлений stdout и stderr, ну и в целом вместо логирования принтами. Например, с помощью [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) можно обернуть функции в декоратор `@logger.catch`, ошибки будут писаться в лог, с подробной информацией (понятное дело, это не ответ на вопрос, почему у вас не работает, просто рекомендация)

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский Да, тогда непонятно. Могут быть какие-то тонкости самого `pyinstller`. А может быть так, что в каталог вам писать нельзя, но при этом там создан файл `err.txt` в который у вас есть права писать. Много чего может быть.

Comment: Файлы с нуля создаются. Да и по большому счёту каталог - обычная папка с обычными правами доступа на условном диске D:\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вопрос не болтался.. хотя полноценного ответа на данный вопрос нет, есть замечание, что стандартный поток и ошибки всё же выводятся в соответствующие файлы. Однако это происходит только тогда, когда скомпилированный файл завершил свою работу и более не является процессом. По его завершении весь стандартный поток также выводится в файл (out.txt в данном случае). Различное (на первый взгляд) поведение потока ошибок и потока выводов обусловлено тем, что при возникновении необработанного исключения работа скомпилированного файла также обрывается и весь вывод пишется в файл. А если программа работает штатно и "долго" (особенно характерно для Телеграмм ботов), вывод в файл будет заморожен до завершения процесса.